# Set byte if positive

Tags: assembly, x86

From the page for [`SETcc`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/setcc), I can do a test to see if a (signed) number is negative with:

```
test %ax, %ax
sets %r10b
```

And if a number is zero with:

```
test %ax, %ax
setz %r10b
```

Is there a conditional to check if something is positive. I was looking for one with ZF=0 and SF=0, if that exists. What's the suggested way to check if a (signed) number is positive?

The only thing I could think of was:

```
cmp %ax, $0
setg %r10b
```

Is there a way to do this with `test` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use

```
    test %ax, %ax
    setg %r10b
```

As you can see on the page you linked, the precise definition of the `setg` instruction is that it sets its operand if ZF = 0 and SF = OF, i.e. if the zero flag is clear and the sign flag equals the overflow flag.  The `test` instruction is [defined to clear the overflow flag](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/test), so in this case `setg` sets its operand if ZF = 0 and SF = 0, which is precisely when the value being tested was strictly positive.

Likewise you can use `setle` after `test` to set if the value was nonpositive, and in this context `setge` and `setl` are equivalent to `setns` and `sets` respectively.

The same goes for the conditional jump instructions, of course.

[As usual, gcc and clang know this trick.](https://godbolt.org/z/hvof4M)